# How to break out from maphash in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to exit early from `maphash` when I've found what I was looking for.

```
(defun find-in-hash (str hash)
  (let ((match nil))
    (maphash (lambda (key value)
      (if (string-prefix-p str key)
        (setq match key))) hash)
    match))
```

How would I do this in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: Is [Emacs Lisp: Ways to Exit/Break a Loop](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_break_loop.html) or [how to interrupt maphash](http://osdir.com/ml/lisp.allegro/2006-04/msg00018.html) of help?

Comment: That is not a correct form (unmatched parentheses, misleading indentation).

Comment: Have you thought about using a trie instead?

Comment: @N.N certainly! `block` and `return-from` seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Svante good point! Though trie doesn't fit this specific case. The code is out of context and slightly modified.

Comment: BTW, you can replace `maphash + string-prefix-p` with `all-completions` and then put the `throw` within the `pred` argument: `(catch 'found (all-completions str hash (lambda (key _val) (throw 'found key))))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in [how to interrupt maphash](http://osdir.com/ml/lisp.allegro/2006-04/msg00018.html) you can place a `maphash` inside a block and exit the block via `return-from`, i.e. use the form

```
(block stop-mapping
  (maphash
   ;; Function to call for all entries in ht.
   ;; A condition for when to stop mapping.
     (return-from stop-mapping)
   ht))
```

Note that this requires `cl` which can be required via `(require 'cl)`. [As mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942513/how-to-break-out-from-maphash-in-emacs-lisp#comment22725803_15942774) the same result can be achieved in pure elisp via

```
(catch 'stop-mapping
  (maphash
   ;; Function to call for all entries in ht.
   ;; A condition for when to stop mapping.
     (throw 'stop-mapping retval)
   ht))
```

Comment: The code above require the use of `cl`.  You can get the same result in "plain Elisp" if you replace `block stop-mapping` with `catch 'stop-mapping` and `return-from top-mapping` with `throw 'stop-mapping`.

Comment: @Stefan But both `block` and `return-from` seems available on my installation of Emacs as they are documented.

Comment: They're only available after you `(require 'cl)`.  Most likely some other package you're using has done this `require`, which is why you see them.  In any case, `block` and `return-from` are macros implemented in the `cl` package and they expand to code that uses `catch` and `throw`.

Comment: @Stefan I see. Thanks for the information. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of self-promotion here :)

I've been working (although not quite as much recently) on a set of macros to make it more uniform and, hopefully, easier to do all kinds of iteration on various collections available in Emacs Lisp. Here it is: https://code.google.com/p/i-iterate/ it is not 100% finished and tested, but for the most part it is.

As has already been said, the only way to break from `maphash` is to throw an error. But this is just something Emacs Lisp acquired at the time it was designed. Many older languages have special primitives for iterating over particular collections, or for performing numerical iteration, while they don't have a language-level abstraction of iteration. `loop` macro in `cl` package in Emacs Lisp is one (good) way to address the situation, but by its nature it has to mirror the same macro in Common Lisp, and that macro isn't extensible (you cannot add your own drivers to it, even if some implementation allows it).

The library I worked on tries to follow in spirit another Common Lisp library: `iterate` and borrows many ideas from there.

Just to illustrate what `loop` macro can do:

```
(loop with hash = (make-hash-table)
      initially 
      (setf (gethash 'a hash) 'b
            (gethash 'b hash) 'b
            (gethash 'c hash) 'c)      ; initialize variables 
                                       ; before any iteration happens
      for x being the hash-key in hash
      using (hash-value y)             ; define variables used in iteration
      collect (list x y) into z        ; some predefined functionality
      until (eq x y)                   ; termination condition
      finally (return (cons 'd z)))    ; returning from iteration
;; (d (a b) (b b))
```

With the benefit of it working similarly for hash tables, arrays or lists.

Similar code using `++` macro:

```
(++ (with ((hash (let ((h (make-hash-table)))
                   (setf (gethash 'a h) 'b
                         (gethash 'b h) 'b
                         (gethash 'c h) 'c) h))))
  (for (x . y) pairs hash)
  (collect (list x y) into z)
  (when (eq x y) (return (cons 'd z))))
;; (d (b b) (a b))
```

(I don't have anything analogous to `initially` yet)