# How to exit from a function at any arbitrary point, in elisp

Tags: function, emacs, elisp, exit

This is a simple question, but somehow I couldn't find an answer by googling:

How do you exit a function at any arbitrary point of execution, if some condition is not met. For example (I use "(exit)" as a substitute here):

```el
(defun foo ()
  (progn (if (/= a1 a2)
             (exit) ; if a1!=a2, exit the function somehow
           t)
         (blahblah...)))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In elisp, you can use `catch` and `throw` [instead of cl's `block` and `return-from`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942513/how-to-break-out-from-maphash-in-emacs-lisp#comment22726001_15942774).

```el
(defun foo ()
  (catch 'my-tag
    (when (not (/= a1 a2))
      (throw 'my-tag "non-local exit value"))
    "normal exit value"))
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Nonlocal Exits` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

Put a block around the body and return from it:

```
(require 'cl-macs)
(defun foo ()
  (block foo
    (if (/= a1 a2)
        (return-from foo)
        reture-value))))
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use `defun*` instead of `defun` (comes with `cl` package). This macro already acts like Common Lisp's `defun` (wraps the body of the function in a try-catch block and aliases `return-from` to `throw` etc.).

For example:

```
(require 'cl)

(defun* get-out-early ()
  "Get out early from this silly example."
  (when (not (boundp some-unbound-symbol))
    (return-from get-out-early))
  ;;
  ;; Get on with the func...
  ;;
  (do-such-and-such with-some-stuff))
```

Answer (score 3):

A function returns the value of the last form evaluated. If you don't care what the value is, then `nil` would be a likely candidate. In this case, the function returns the value of the `if` function.

e.g.:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (if (/= a1 a2)
      nil
    "return-value"))
```

In this trivial example, these would also be equivalent:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (if (not (/= a1 a2))
      "return-value"))

(defun foo ()
  (when (not (/= a1 a2))
    "return-value"))
```

Comment: :That's not my question. sorry, my previous example is misleading. I changed it.

Comment: Ah, okay. In the majority of situations you should be able to structure your code so as to avoid the need for non-local exits, but I've added another answer with the standard elisp approach to doing that.